# Stream Precision Modifier for strings

Tags: c++, printf, precision, cout, iomanip

Lets say I have `string foo("lorem ipsum")`. Now i want to print a maximum number of characters from `foo`, let's say `x` which is guaranteed to be smaller than `foo.size()`.

This is very continent in `printf`:

```
printf("%.*s", x, foo.data());
```

But the only way I can find to do this in a stream is to construct a temporary `string`:

```
cout << string(foo, x);
```

Is there a manipulator that will let me set the precision for streams, or is constructing a temporary `string` all that's available to me?

Comment: I don't know of a "maniuplator way" to do this, but [`string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view) is the way to go here. It is not in the standard yet, however.

Comment: @NathanOliver What are you saying it doesn't work with `string`? http://ideone.com/quH7cl

Comment: @NathanOliver Ah yes, `setw` is for numeric values only. Even if not, the width field specifies the minimum in `printf`. It's the precision field that specifies the maximum. So `setprecision` is what we would be looking for, if it did in fact work for `string`s (which it doesn't.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "stream manipulator" to cut off strings after a specified width.

What you're looking for is basically [`string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view)<sup>(1)</sup>, that is some light weight substring wrapper which is ostream-able.

The following line would print the first `x` characters of `foo` without copying it to a temporary string, as long as the guarantee you mention (`x >= foo.size()`) holds:

```
cout << string_view(foo.data(), x);
```

In case the guarantee doesn't hold anymore, use `setw` to fill the field with whitespaces when the string is shorter, in order to print a fixed field length of `x` characters. The `string_view` constructor needs a properly bound-limited length since it doesn't know the size of the "real" `std::string` object, thus we use `min` to limit `x` to the length of the string:

```
cout << setw(x) << string_view(foo.data(), min(x, foo.size()));
```

---

If you don't want to or can't use `string_view`, you can write your own light weight wrapper just for the purpose of printing a substring with ostream.

```
class substr {
     const std::string & s;
     std::size_t len;

     friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const substr &ss) {
         std::copy(ss.s.begin(), ss.s.begin() + std::min(ss.len, ss.s.size()),
                   std::ostream_iterator<char>(os));
         return os;
     }
public:
     substr(const std::string & s, std::size_t len) : s(s), len(len) {}
};
```

The usage is then:

```
cout << substr(foo, x);
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://ideone.com/FlivP9)</kbd>

---

<sup>(1) This class is currently experimental and not yet in the standard.  As far as I know, it probably will be in C++17 and is available as `std::experimental::string_view` in `<experimental/string_view>` since g++ 4.9 when using `-std=c++1y` or `17`.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

This is not a stream manipulator but you can use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) and copy the number of characters you want into the output stream.  This avoid the construction of a temporary string.

```
int main() {
    std::string s = "this is a test";
    std::copy(s.begin(), s.begin() + 7, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
this is
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6867ca0f3182e76d)</kbd>

Comment: It's depressing to think that this is as good as we can do with streams.